# Java jFugue music play

Tags: java, jfugue

```
import org.jfugue.player.Player;

public class MusicPlayer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwelveBarBlues twelveBarBlues = new TwelveBarBlues();

        System.out.println("Twelve Bar blues Playing: ");

        Player player = new Player();
        player.play(twelveBarBlues.getPattern());

        }

}

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jfugue.pattern.Pattern;
import org.jfugue.player.Player;
import org.jfugue.theory.ChordProgression;

public class TwelveBarBlues {

private String pattern;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Pattern pattern = new ChordProgression("I IV V")
            .distribute("7%6")
            .allChordsAs("$0 $0 $0 $0 $1 $1 $0 $0 $2 $1 $0 $0")
            .eachChordAs("$0ia100 $1ia80 $2ia80 $3ia80 $4ia100 $3ia80 $2ia80 $1ia80")
            .getPattern()
            .setInstrument("Acoustic_Bass")
            .setTempo(100);
    new Player().play(pattern);
}

public String getPattern() {
    this.pattern = pattern;
    return pattern;
    }
}
```

I want to play the twelveBarBlue music code at MusicPlayer.
but I got error code
Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.length()" because "this.text" is null
when I run the MusicPlayer
[MusicPlayer Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzb7G.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute MusicPlayer, it calls `main()` in MusicPlayer but `main()` in TwelveBarBlues is never called, so in `getPattern()`, 'pattern' has never been set, and you're returning null.

Instead, change TwelveBarBlues so `getPattern()` returns the pattern that you currently have in `main()`. Just move the code from `main()` into `getPattern()`, then remove the `main()` method, since you're not running TwelveBarBlues as its own program.

Or, keep the `main()` method in case you want to use that class as its own executable, but have it call its own `getPattern()` method. You'll need to do something like `TwelveBarBlues blues = new TwelveBarBlues();` and then `new Player().play(blues.getPattern());`.